# how to disable warning message and instead show the other message in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$html_url = 'http://api.biblia.com/v1/bible/content/LEB.html?passage=John333&style=fullyFormatted&key=fd37d8';
$str_html  = file_get_contents($html_url);
```

Question:

It shows: Warning: `file_get_contents(http://api.biblia.com/v1...`

Is there a way that can hide this message, instead show a message such as "can not show the result"?

Comment: Mostly file_get_contents( is disabled on remote servers. You should use PHP Curl to get the html content from a url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @ symbol like this:

```
$html_url = 'http://api.biblia.com/v1/bible/content/LEB.html?passage=John333&style=fullyFormatted&key=fd37d8';
$str_html  = @file_get_contents($html_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `@` to suppress warning..but it is not a preferable method to suppress warning/notices/errors, instead you should try to debug your code to check what is going wrong behind the scene.

`error_reporting()` is another way of handling these errors.

Comment: Which one is preferable then?

Comment: my lateer comment makes it more clear with what preferable means in the current context

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(0);
```

try [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)